# Is it correct to use 2 instances of Redis server one with persistence while the second with no persistence?

Tags: database-design, redis

I'm starting a new project. In this project I'll use Redis to store some data which must be persistent. For these data I'll use `Append Only File (AOF)` persistence.

In the project there are 2 applications that must communicate with each other. To allow this communication I'm thinking to use Redis as a *"shared memory"*. With the term *"shared memory"* I mean that the use of Redis is:

- to store some keys (called `keyA1`, `keyA2`) that will be updated by application A
- to store other keys updated by application B (called `keyB1`, `keyB2`)
- application A reads the keys updated by Application B (`keyB1`, `keyB2`)
- Application B reads the keys updated by Application A (`keyA1`, `keyA2`)

This group of keys (`keyA1`, `keyA2`, `keyB1`, `keyB2`) must not be saved on persistent memory.

My idea is *to use Redis to avoid the creation of a TCP communication protocol between Application A and Application B* (but I have the doubt that this is use of Redis could not be correct).
Each of these 2 applications sends messages to the other and receives messages from the other by *writing and reading keys of the Redis database*.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75291286/is-it-possible-to-enable-persistance-for-some-part-of-the-redis-data) tells that is not possible activate persistence for only a subset of database keys so I'm thinking to use 2 instances of Redis.

Is it correct to use 2 instances of Redis server (one on the default port 6379 and the other on the port 6380) and setup the first with AOF persistence while the second with no persistence?
Is there a better approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I can answer to my question. I and my workmates, have implemented the code of the Application A and the Application B that use a Redis instance (on port 6380) with no persistence to communicate as explained in the question.

Furthermore we have used an other Redis instance (default port 6379) with AOF persistence to store data on persistent memory. We use the standard file `/etc/redis/redis.conf` to configure this second Redis instance.

This architecture works correctly for our needs. In particular Application A and Application B can communicate by the writing/reading of some keys (see the question) stored in the Redis instance on port 6380. These keys are modified up to 2 or 3 times per second and this frequency, in our context, is sufficient.

For completeness I show below the configuration of Redis to disable persistence.

##### No persistence Redis configuration

To configure this Redis instance we have created the configuration file `/etc/redis/redis_6380.conf`. The most important options for this file are:

```
port 6380

# RDB persistence disabled
save ""

# The working directory.
dir /var/lib/redis/6380

# AOF persistence disabled
appendonly no
```

---

##### Links

- This [article](https://nadeauinnovations.com/post/2018/07/interprocess-communication-with-redis/) speaks about Redis as a Simple Interprocess Communication: my use of Redis could be considered a way to implement the IPC between Application A and Application B.
- In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14320651/redis-is-how-to-achieve-inter-process-communication/14320898#14320898) the author says:

> TCP sockets can be used to perform both network and local inter-process communication. Unix domain sockets can only support local inter-process communication.

This means that to increase the speed of my software I can use `Unix domain sockets` instead of TCP sockets.
Always about the author of the post, the use of `Unix domain sockets` for IPC with Redis could give this improvement:

> you can process 50% more operations when using unix domain sockets.